# PHP ошибка в сериализации JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel, php-fpm

Доброго времени суток!

У меня есть небольшой json rest-api сервис который при запросе на домашний адрес должен выдавать информацию о сервисе. Недавно я решил перейти с Apache на nginx и php-fpm.

Я использую php-fpm8.1 при запросе на / я получаю огромную ошибку ( я укажу её ниже ) Как я понял это ошибка при сериализации в json. Я попробовал серилиализовать массив в json при помощи команды
`json_encode($arr);`и всё прекрасно сработало. В чём может быть проблема? Возможно я пропустил какое-то расширение. Буду безумно благодарен любому ответу

> ошибка

[image: ошибка которую выдаёт php-fpm]

> текстовый вариант ошибки

```
Fatal error: During inheritance of JsonSerializable:
Uncaught ErrorException: Declaration of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::jsonSerialize() should be compatible with JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize(): mixed in /var/www/project/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php:1358
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/project/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php(24): Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}(8192, 'Declaration of ...', '/var/www/projec...', 1358)
#1 /var/www/project/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(478): include('/var/www/projec...') 
#2 /var/www/project/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(346): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/var/www/projec...') 
#3 /var/www/project/vendor/illuminate/database/DatabaseServiceProvider.php(42): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\\Data...') 
#4 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(233): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider->register() 
#5 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(665): Laravel\Lumen\Application->register(Object(Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider)) 
#6 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(410): Laravel\Lumen\Application->loadComponent('database', Array, 'db') 
#7 /var/www/project/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(829): Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\{closure}(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array) 
#8 /var/www/project/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(714): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure)) 
#9 /var/www/project/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(652): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('db', Array) 
#10 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(300): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('db', Array) 
#11 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(778): Laravel\Lumen\Application->make('db') 
#12 /var/www/project/bootstrap/app.php(28): Laravel\Lumen\Application->withEloquent() 
#13 /var/www/project/public/index.php(14): require('/var/www/projec...') 
#14 {main} in /var/www/project/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 24

Fatal error: During inheritance of JsonSerializable:
 Uncaught ErrorException: Declaration of Illuminate\Support\Collection::jsonSerialize() should be compatible with JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize(): mixed in /var/www/project/vendor/illuminate/collections/Collection.php:836
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/project/vendor/illuminate/collections/Collection.php(13): Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}(8192, 'Declaration of ...', '/var/www/projec...', 836)
#1 /var/www/project/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(478): include('/var/www/projec...')
#2 /var/www/project/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(346): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/var/www/projec...')
#3 /var/www/project/vendor/illuminate/collections/helpers.php(15): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\\Supp...')
#4 /var/www/project/vendor/illuminate/log/LogManager.php(244): collect(Array)
#5 /var/www/project/vendor/illuminate/log/LogManager.php(202): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->createStackDriver(Array)
#6 /var/www/project/vendor/illuminate/log/LogManager.php(118): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->resolve('stack')
#7 /var/www/project/vendor/illuminate/log/LogManager.php(98): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->get('stack')
#8 /var/www/project/vendor/illuminate/log/LogManager.php(555): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->driver() 
#9 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Exceptions/Handler.php(56): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->error('During inherita...', Array)
#10 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RegistersExceptionHandlers.php(119): Laravel\Lumen\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError)) 
#11 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RegistersExceptionHandlers.php(67): Laravel\Lumen\Application->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError)) 
#12 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RegistersExceptionHandlers.php(55): Laravel\Lumen\Application->handleShutdown() 
#13 [internal function]: Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}() 
#14 {main} in /var/www/project/vendor/illuminate/collections/Collection.php on line 13
```

Comment: вы же поменяли не только апач на nginx но и версию пхп сменили. Написано у вас, сигнатура методов не совпадает. откройте два указанных файла класса и сравните сигнатуры, отредактируйте чтобы совпадало. либо обновите фреймворк.

Comment: да, но на апач у меня стояла версия php 8, но спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Да оказалось что в 8.1 вырезали интерфейс Serializeble я откатил fpm до 8 версии и всё заработало. Спасибо тебе я бы тебя поцеловал если бы знал где ты :) в общем огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как отметил [@teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223826/teran) проблема была в сигнатуре метода. Решением оказалось откат php-fpm с 8.1 до 8 версии.

Еще раз спасибо огромное!